# How to load bin to Cortex-M4 in Google Coral Dev

Tags: cortex-m, google-coral, mendel-os

- Currently I'm trying to load `hello_world.bin` to cortex m4 from u-boot in Google coral dev

#### What I've tried?

- Bring up Coral dev target

  - Followed steps in https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/
  - Able to get mendel OS prompt in /dev/ttyUSB0(host)->ttymxc0(target)
  - Able to `mdt shell`
  - Target ready with u-boot->kernel image->rootfs
- SDK for i.MX8MQ

  - Download SDK from https://mcuxpresso.nxp.com/
  - For processor 'MIMX8MQ6xxxJZ' (auto selects Boards - EVK-MIMX8MQ)
  - Build `hello_world.bin` for Cortex M4 (TCM based). Uses UART2 in `BOARD_InitBootPins`

```
$ tar -xzf SDK_2.8.0_MIMX8MQ6xxxJZ.tar.gz
$ cd boards/evkmimx8mq/demo_apps/hello_world/armgcc
$ export ARMGCC_DIR=<path to>/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/
$ export PATH=$PATH:<path to>/gcc-arm-none-eabi-9-2020-q2-update/bin
$ ./build_debug.sh 
$ ls debug/hello_world.bin
```

- Load `hello_world.bin` from u-boot

  - I've placed my bin in tftpboot location.

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0 
u-boot=> tftp 0x7e0000 192.168.0.33:/tftpboot/coral/boot/hello_world.bin
Using ethernet@30be0000 device
TFTP from server 192.168.0.33; our IP address is 192.168.0.133
Filename '/tftpboot/coral/boot/hello_world.bin'.
Load address: 0x7e0000
Loading: ####
         2.3 MiB/s
done
Bytes transferred = 16700 (413c hex)
u-boot=> bootaux 0x7e0000
## Starting auxiliary core at 0x007E0000 ...
```

- But I'm not able to see any output on the second terminal ttyUSB1
- Expected output should be `Hello World` on the second terminal

#### What I've Observed

- In [Coral-Dev-Board-baseboard-schematic.pdf](https://storage.googleapis.com/site_and_emails_static_assets/Files/Coral-Dev-Board-baseboard-schematic.pdf)

  - According to Baseboard block diagram, `UART2/3` is connected to MicroUSB via converter

    - But UART1(ttymxc0) is also available on micro USB
    - After kernel boot UART3(ttymxc0) is available on micro USB
  - But after kernel boot, I noticed UART3 to be available on second enumerated port
  - For example,

```
// On coral dev
root@wishful-zebra:~# ls -las /dev/ttymxc*
0 crw------- 1 mendel tty     207, 16 Aug 20 03:45 /dev/ttymxc0
0 crw-rw---- 1 root   dialout 207, 17 Aug 20 03:05 /dev/ttymxc1
0 crw-rw---- 1 root   dialout 207, 18 Aug 20 03:40 /dev/ttymxc2

root@wishful-zebra:~# stty -echo raw speed 115200 < /dev/ttymxc2
115200
root@wishful-zebra:~# echo "test" > /dev/ttymxc2 

// prints 'test' on /dev/ttyUSB1 host side
Welcome to minicom 2.7.1

OPTIONS: I18n 
Compiled on Aug 13 2017, 15:25:34.
Port /dev/ttyUSB1, 23:55:15

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys

test
```

#### Question

- How to load firmware to Cortex M4 on Google Coral Dev?
- Which i.MX SDK port to use for Google Coral Dev?
- What are the UARTs available on the micro USB?
- Which UART is used for Cortex M4 in Google Coral Dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the instructions to boot the imx8m M4 and run the TFLite Micro Hello World (outputs a sine wave) on it:
https://coral.googlesource.com/mcuxpresso_sdk/+/refs/heads/master/boards/evkmimx8mq/demo_apps/hello_world_tflite/.

you'll need to sync the project repo and rebuild linux-imx and uboot-imx.

Output from the M4 core will be visible on the second UART that enumerated when you connected your serial port via USB.

Comment: Thank you. Above ref repository works. Except that copying bin to `/boot` directory and setting `m4enabled` did not work for me. Loading bin and `bootaux` works as mentioned in i.MX8 ref manuals.

Comment: @ChehtanSuresh Did you also try the freeRTOS example given at https://coral.googlesource.com/mcuxpresso_sdk/+/refs/heads/master/boards/evkmimx8mq/rtos_examples/freertos_hello/ ?

Comment: yes I tried the `multicore_examples/rpmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos` from the same repository. I hope it's fine to capture the steps below.

Answer (score 1):

- As mentioned in the above accepted answer, we can use the `mcuxpresso_sdk` to build bin/elf for the Coral Dev CM4.
- Additionally I'd to capture details to use the `multicore_example`,`rtos_example` from the Coral repo.
- Also I'd like to add points on rpmsg/remoteproc support for imx8mq in linux kernel v4.14, the required patches adn dts support for imx8mq.

### FreeRTOS SDK example - Boot CM4 from u-boot

- SDK source for Coral Dev

  - https://coral.googlesource.com/mcuxpresso_sdk/+/refs/heads/master/boards/evkmimx8mq
- `hello_world_tflite` example works without any changes.

  - Why? in `main.c` the `BOARD_InitPins` function is called which configures the UART pins for the CM4 console (in `pin_mux.c`)
- This configuration is not applied for other examples. Therefore, I copied files `board.h, board.c, clock_config.c, clock_config.h, pin_mux.c, pin_mux.h` from hello_world_tflite to other example projects.
- And `BOARD_InitPins()` must be called
- **Example for `rtos_examples/freertos_hello`**

```sh
$ cd mcuxpresso_sdk/boards/evkmimx8mq/rtos_examples/freertos_hello/

// copy board files from hello_word_tflite example
$ cp -rf ../../demo_apps/hello_world_tflite/[pin_mux.* board.* clock_config.*] ./

// freertos_hello.c -> main -> BOARD_InitBootPins() -> BOARD_InitPins()
// Update pin_mux.c, BOARD_InitBootPins() call BOARD_InitPins()
void BOARD_InitBootPins(void)
  {
+   BOARD_InitPins();
  }

$ cd armgcc
//compile your project
// copy release/freertos_hello.bin to your SDcard/emmc/tftpboot location 
// I use tftp

u-boot=> tftp 0x7e0000 192.168.0.33:/tftpboot/coral/boot/freertos_hello.bin
u-boot=> bootaux 0x7e0000 

// Open other emulated console and verify output
```

### Load CM4 elf from Linux Remoteproc

#### Linux kernel support

- The CM4 can be loaded from linux side using remoteproc support
- I did not find remoteproc support for imx8mq in https://coral.googlesource.com/linux-imx/
- But there were set of patches available for imx8mq remoteproc support here

  - https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-remoteproc/list/?series=323535
- And basically we cannot enable `IMX_REMOTEPROC` because of the same reason
- For my experimental support and learning I applied only the [[08/10] remoteproc: imx_rproc: support i.MX8MQ/M](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/11682489/) patch
- And added Kconfig support for `IMX_REMOTEPROC` by adding `HAVE_IMX8_SOC`, which let's me enable remoteproc for IMX8MQ

#### Linux DTS support

- This is my current dts smip from `arch/arm64/boot/dts/freescale/fsl-imx8mq-phanbell.dts`. (Add at the top of dts file)

```
/ {
  reserved-memory {
    #address-cells = <2>;
    #size-cells = <2>;
    ranges;

    m4_reserved: m4@0x80000000 {
      no-map;
      reg = <0 0x80000000 0 0x1000000>;
    };  
  };  
  imx8mq-cm4 {
         compatible    = "fsl,imx8mq-cm4";
         memory-region = <&m4_reserved>;
         syscon        = <&src>;
         clocks        = <&clk IMX8MQ_CLK_M4_ROOT>;
     };  
};
&rpmsg{
  /*  
   * 64K for one rpmsg instance:
   * --0xb8000000~0xb800ffff: pingpong
   */
  vdev-nums = <1>;
  reg = <0x0 0xb8000000 0x0 0x10000>;
  status = "okay";
};

&uart2{
    status="disabled";
};

&uart3{
    status="disabled";
};
```

#### Linux RPMsg support

- I enabled the imx rpmsg module examples `IMX_RPMSG_TTY and IMX_RPMSG_PINGPONG`
- Also enabled `RPMSG_CHAR`
- Also CM4 application side rpmsg readme can be found [here](https://coral.googlesource.com/mcuxpresso_sdk/+/refs/heads/master/boards/evkmimx8mq/multicore_examples/rpmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos/readme.txt)

---

- With above listed changes to linux kernel and CM4 sdk application examples, we can use the remoteproc to laod elf to CM4 and use `pmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos` example to communicate between APU and M4

---

#### Example CM4 elf load using remoteproc

- Load ddr build `hello_world.elf` using remoteproc. The elf file is expected to be in `/lib/firmware` of your coral rootfs. Copy to respective location.

```
$ cd /path/to/mcuxpresso_sdk/...../hello_world/armgcc
$ ./build_ddr_release.sh 
$ sudo cp ddr_release/hello_world.elf (sdcard/emmc/nfs rootfs)/lib/firmware/

// load firmware using remoteproc
root@coraldev:~# echo hello_world_tflite.elf > /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc0/firmware 
root@coraldev:~# echo start > /sys/class/remoteproc/remoteproc0/state 


[  109.365150] remoteproc remoteproc0: powering up imx-rproc
[  109.372949] remoteproc remoteproc0: Booting fw image hello_world_tflite.elf, size 295228
[  109.381399] remoteproc remoteproc0: filesz 0x240 memsz 0x240
[  109.387196] remoteproc remoteproc0: da 0x80000000 mem 0x240
[  109.392959] remoteproc remoteproc0: filesz 0x1ee78 memsz 0x1ee78
[  109.399094] remoteproc remoteproc0: da 0x80000240 mem 0x1ee78
[  109.405366] remoteproc remoteproc0: filesz 0x6f4 memsz 0x6f4
[  109.411181] remoteproc remoteproc0: da 0x8001f0b8 mem 0x6f4
[  109.416945] remoteproc remoteproc0: filesz 0x0 memsz 0x3ba8
[  109.422638] remoteproc remoteproc0: da 0x8001f7c0 mem 0x3ba8
[  109.428501] remoteproc remoteproc0: remote processor imx-rproc is now up
```

- But sometimes I'm not able to view M4 UART console
- Loading any other example than `hello_world*` I get `bad phdr da 0x80000000 mem 0x240`. This I'm not sure how to resolve

  - Maybe dts mem reg should be updated
  - Maybe wait for official support for imx8mq remoteproc
- But basic learning and experiment works

#### Linux side rpmsg char driver example

- Compile `multicore_examples/rpmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos/armgcc` with update board init pins
- Load the bin from u-boot
- After linux boots, up insmod the `imx_rpmsg_tty.ko` (need to enabled in menuconfig)

```
// Load cm4 
u-boot=> tftp 0x7e0000 192.168.0.33:/tftpboot/coral/boot/rpmsg_lite_str_echo_rtos_imxcm4.bin
u-boot=> bootaux 0x7e0000 

// on linux side
root@coraldev:~# insmod /lib/modules/4.14.98+/kernel/drivers/rpmsg/imx_rpmsg_tty.ko 
root@coraldev:~# ls -las /dev/ttyRPMSG30 
     0 crw-rw----    1 root     dialout   235,   0 Jan  1 04:52 /dev/ttyRPMSG30

root@coraldev:~# echo "hello from linux" > /dev/ttyRPMSG30 

// on CM4 console, other emulated ttyUSB1 
RPMSG String Echo FreeRTOS RTOS API Demo...

Nameservice sent, ready for incoming messages...
Get Message From Master Side : "hello world!" [len : 12]
Get Message From Master Side : "hello from linux" [len : 16]
Get New Line From Master Side
```

---

- I've tried to update here everything I tried about using CM4 in coral dev
- I'm still facing issues with remoteproc.
- I hope some of these information are helpful for anyone stumbling across this post